# How to set dynamic value to minView in datetimepicker?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm implementing Dale Lotts [datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker) in my app.
I want to change the value of minView dynamically from minute to day.
I have tried something like this.

In HTML:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateModel" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: 'id', minView: 'minute', configureOn:'change' }"/>
```

In JS:

```
scope.config = "{ dropdownSelector: 'id', minView: 'day',configureOn:'change' }";

setTimeout(function () {scope.$broadcast('change', scope.config);}, 500);
```

I want to set `minView` property as day at one place and minute at another place with this datetimepicker .

Please suggest.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I have used this datepicker at two places. I want minView as day at one place and minute at another place.

Comment: There is an option configureOn but It is not very clear how to implement it.
You can check this issue. https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/8

Comment: Have you looked at the code in the demo directory? https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/demo/demo-controller.js#L56 and https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/demo/demo-controller.js#L107 and https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/demo/index.html#L367

Comment: @dale.lotts Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Thank you @dale.lotts

in HTML:

```
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateModel" data-datetimepicker-config="config.configureOnConfig"></datetimepicker>
```

in JS:

```
$scope.config = {
    configureOnConfig: {
        dropdownSelector: 'id',
        minView: 'minute',
        configureOn: 'config-changed'
    }
};

$scope.changeConfig=function(){
    $scope.config.configureOnConfig.minView = 'day';
    $scope.$broadcast('config-changed');
}
```

Call *$scope.changeConfig* function when you need to change the configuration.